# CSRF token not rendered if using Context({dict}) vs just {dict}

Tags: django, csrf, django-context

Does anyone know why the following renders my template ok:

```
c= {'render_form' : form }
return render(request, 'page1.html', c)
```

but the following does not render the csrf token:

```
c= Context({'render_form' : form}) 
return render(request, 'page1.html', c)
```

The template looks like this:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ render_form }}
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" class='btn' id="submitbutton" name="_submit" />
</form>
```

I want to keep `render()` and I would like to avoid using `locals()`.

Comment: I don't understand why you would use Context explicitly though. Just pass a dictionary, that's what you're supposed to do.

Comment: I thought I was supposed to.  I was trying to follow the examples in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#playing-with-context.  I'll just stick to the one that works then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your Django version, but the render method used to take two context related arguments, `context` and `context_instance`, the latter expects a `Context` or `RequestContext` object, the first a dictionary. The documentation has some specific deprecation details:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#optional-arguments

Comment: thanks that helped.  I'm using 1.8. I thought I was supposed to pass a context object.